# the supremum is necessarily an element of the set itself?

Tags: real-analysis

For any non-empty set of real numbers which is bounded above, can we claim that the supremum is necessarily an element of the set itself? You must prove all your claims.

Please help me to solve this. I want a general proof. Proof by counterexample is not enough, according to my teacher.

$${}$$

Comment: Providing a counterexample should be sufficient. Why doesn't your teacher accept it? What does a general proof mean?

Comment: Could you at least add here "your" definition of supremum? This could help you and us.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the two following sets:

1. $(0,1)$
2. $[0,1]$

From these, we can conclude what statements are true for general bounded subsets of reals.

Answer (score 0):

The logical opposite of

> "*For any non-empty set of real numbers which is bounded above, the supremum is necessarily an element of the set itself*"

is

> "*For some non-empty set of real numbers which is bounded above, the supremum is not an element of the set itself*"

Or in other words,

> "*There exists a non-empty set of real numbers which is bounded above whose supremum is not an element of the set itself*"

or even more concisely,

> "*There exists a counterexample to the original statement.*"

Now, in order to prove that a general statement along the lines of "*for every...*", we would need a "general proof", the kind you claim to need for this problem.  However, the statement is not true, so we do **not** want to give a general proof.  Rather, we want to give a proof of the logical opposite, which is simply "*there exists a counterexample*".  In order to show that a counterexample exists, it suffices to provide a counterexample.

One suitable counterexample is the set $\{x \in \mathbb{R} : 0 \leq x < 1\}$.